# Easier way to require spec files in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a `spec_helper` that looks like this:

```
require 'pry'
require 'helpers/data_helper.rb'
require 'distributer.rb'
require 'house_distributer.rb'
require 'accounting_service.rb'
require 'mixer_worker.rb'
require 'mixer.rb'
require 'transaction_service.rb'

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.warnings = true

  config.order = :random
end
```

and a folder structure that looks like this:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.md
├── app.rb
├── config.ru
├── lib
│   ├── accounting_service.rb
│   ├── distributer.rb
│   ├── house_distributer.rb
│   ├── mixer.rb
│   ├── mixer_worker.rb
│   └── transaction_service.rb
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── add_coins.css
│   ├── images
│   │   └── bitcoin_dawg.jpg
│   └── javascripts
│       └── add_coins.js
├── spec
│   ├── helpers
│   │   └── data_helper.rb
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── accounting_service_spec.rb
│   │   └── transaction_service_spec.rb
│   └── spec_helper.rb
└── views
    └── add_coins.erb
```

This does not work:

```
Dir["lib/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }

[1] pry(main)> Dir["lib/*.rb"]
=> ["lib/house_distributer.rb", "lib/distributer.rb", "lib/mixer.rb", "lib/accounting_service.rb", "lib/mixer_worker.rb", "lib/transaction_service.rb"]
```

I get this error message:

```
/Users/jwan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- lib/house_distributer.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/jwan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

What can I do to make this easier?

Also side note, `distributer.rb` has to be loaded before `house_distributer.rb` because of this:

```
class HouseDistributer < Distributer
end
```

Comment: in the future, consider using `tree` to get a text version of your directory structure, instead of taking a screenshot

Comment: what is 'tree'? How do I use it? @maxpleaner

Comment: `tree` is a unix command.  See [the tree website](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) to see what the output looks like and install tree. Or if you have homebrew installed, it's as simple as: `brew install tree`.

Comment: I edited my post, thanks for the rec!

Comment: Try:  ``tree `pwd` ``  -- That will get the top directory to print.  Or  do `cd ..` then `tree app`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Some explanation of max pleaner's answer...*

When you write:

```
require 'lib/house_distributer.rb'
```

ruby looks for the file in the directories assigned to the `$LOAD_PATH` environment variable.  `$LOAD_PATH` is an array of Strings, where each String is a path to a directory.  The directories in the $LOAD_PATH array are searched in order, and the first match wins.

If `$LOAD_PATH` contains a directory called:

```
'/Users/7stud/ruby_programs'
```

Then the `require` statement above will look for a file with the absolute path:

```
'/Users/7stud/ruby_programs/lib/house_distributer.rb'
```

You can check which directories are in your `$LOAD_PATH` like this:

```
$ puts $LOAD_PATH
```

This is what I get:

```
/Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib
/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0
/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin14
/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.4.0
/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin14
/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0
/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin14
```

Obviously, your app's files are not in directories like those.

On the other hand, if you `require` a file whose path starts with a `/` or a `.` -- for instance:

```
require './lib/house_distributer.rb'
```

then ruby skips `$LOAD_PATH`, and in this case ruby looks for the file relative to the *current working directory*.  Note however, that the *current working directory* may not be the directory containing the file with the require statement. For instance, if you execute your sinatra program from a different directory, say two levels up from the file containing the `require` statement, then the two levels up directory will be the *current working directory*, and ruby will look for the required file relative to the two levels up directory.

Enter `require_relative`.  `require_relative` will look for the file relative to the path of the current file--not the current working directory.

As a result, you should probably never use `require` with a relative path and instead use `require_relative`.

Note that you can also programmatically add paths to $LOAD_PATH any time you want:

```
$LOAD_PATH << '/Users/7stud/ruby_programs'
```

And if a file called `dog.rb is` in that directory, I can require it like so:

```
require 'dog'  #extension is unnecessary
```

**Response to comment**:

The simplest thing to do would be:

```
$LOAD_PATH << "/Users/jwan/Desktop/programming/interview_questions/gemini/‌​jobcoin_mixer/"
```

But in sinatra, `settings.root` is the path to your app directory, so do:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift settings.root
```

That way you can move your app to another directory without changing anything.

Or, you can remove `lib/` from the front of every path that `Dir[]` returned:

```
require 'pathname'

paths = [
  "lib/house_distributer.rb", 
  "lib/distributer.rb", 
  "lib/mixer.rb", 
  "lib/accounting_service.rb", 
]

new_paths = paths.map do |path|
  pn = Pathname.new path
  pn.relative_path_from(pn.parent).to_s
end

p new_paths

--output:--
["house_distributer.rb", "distributer.rb", "mixer.rb", "accounting_service.rb"]
```

Comment: While far more confusing for a novice user it is generally more idiomatic to alter `$LOAD_PATH` more dynamically. For example: `$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)))` or as many gems do `$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)`

Comment: I think my issue is that Sinatra looks for files in the load path which includes this: `"/Users/jwan/Desktop/programming/interview_questions/gemini/jobcoin_mixer/lib"` so it can't find a file named `lib/something.rb'. How do I get rid of that extra lib?

Comment: @Jwan622,  See bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Jwan622, How is that directory getting in $LOAD_PATH?

Comment: I forget now, but I fixed it. At some point I was manually adding the `jobcoin_mixer/lib` path into the LOAD_PATH, but now I am just adding `jobcoin_mixer` lib to the LOAD_PATH

Comment: @Jwan622, In sinatra, `settings.root` is the path to your app directory, so do `$LOAD_PATH.unshift settings.root`. That way you can move your app to another directory without changing anything. –

Answer (score 2):

The file not found is because you use `"lib/*.rb"` and not `./"lib/*.rb"`.

To ensure the dependencies are loaded in the correct order, you can do this:

1. move HouseDistributor to `lib/distributor/house_distributor.rb`
2. Require files like so:

   ```
   Dir['./lib/**/*.rb']
   .sort_by { |path| path.count("/") }
   .each { |path| require path }
   ```

   this uses `**/*.rb` to do a recursive search and will sort the files by the count of "/" (their depth) before requiring

Just a note of caution, if you are doing a recursive require, keep in mind that you actually do want to require all those files. For example if you are are using ActiveRecord and have a schema.rb file, you probably don't want to require that.

Answer (score 2):

The other 2 answers are technically correct and address the *goal* but not the *aim*. In other words - ***why are you doing that in the first place?*** For instance, why do this:

> Also side note, distributer.rb has to be loaded before house_distributer.rb because of this:

```
class HouseDistributer < Distributer
end
```

And not this?

```
require_relative "distributer.rb"
class HouseDistributer < Distributer
end
```

And in the tests (*cough*) sorry, the *specs*:

```
# spec/house_distributer_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative "../lib/house_distributer.rb"

# spec/transaction_service_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative "../lib/transaction_service.rb"
```

And since `transaction_service.rb` appears to need `HouseDistributer` from `lib/house_distributer.rb`…

```
# lib/transaction_service.rb
require_relative "house_distributer.rb"
```

#### The rule of thumb

*If a file needs another to run then `require` (or `require_relative`) it in the file that requires it.* Then you get:

- A kind of natural sandboxing by only running what is needed (maybe Distributer works perfectly and HouseDistributer has the error because of a monkey patch - how will you know if you `require` files that aren't actually needed?)
- No need to handle requires elsewhere.
- No need (or much less need) to know the order of requires.
- No need to fiddle about with the load path (which has been a dubious need ever since `require_relative` was introduced).
- Changing the load path and then using `require` can break sandboxing and make specs work that should fail by loading a gem you have installed on your system but isn't defined as a dependency in the gemspec.

I'd add, use bundler's sandboxing too, to avoid further errors and let it handle your load path, e.g.

`bundle install --binstubs --path=vendor` (or vendor.noindex on a Mac) then:

`bin/rspec` and whatever commandline args you need.